# Execute a job only when the previous has finished

Tags: bash, sqoop

I have a bash script which has a sqoop exec and after it three impala commands. I want to run it but only when the previous execution has finished. Is this possible to be done in cronjob or in oozie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are in a linux environment so you should be able to use the `run-one` command ( [ubuntu run-one](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/run-one.1.html) ) in conjunction with you bash script in a crontab.

e.g.

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/your/script && run-one ./your-script.sh
```

If not available you should be able to install if with your package manager

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. Can you please explain me what exactly run-one does?

Comment: sure; you can even look at it yourself - it's just a shell script on its own. Type: `cat $(which run-one)` and you'll see the contents of the script file.

essentially the script creates a lock file in the `.cache/run-one/{HASH_OF_CMD}` directory next to where you execute the script and makes sure it doesn't run the command again until this lock file is released by the currently running execution